# I'm receiving this error when running my tests "element not interactable: element not interactable (Session info: headless chrome=111.0.5563.65)"

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io

So I'm working on a practice site for automation testing with WebDriverIO and all of my tests work normally. my issue is when i add the settings to the config file to run chrome in headless mode. just about every test works exect my End2End test. it says that the element is not interactable even though it's a button that take you to the checkout. i'm using it's relative xpath as the locator and when i run the test without headless mode, everything works as it should. does anyone have a solution?

here's the config part:

```
 browserName: 'chrome',
        'goog:chromeOptions': {
            // to run chrome headless the following flags are required
            // (see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)
            args: ['--headless', '--disable-gpu'],
            },
```

I've tried using relative csslocators, and xpath. I've tried only enabling the headless arg in the config. and i also tried enabling both headless mode, and diable gpu args.

Answer (score 0):

I set a window size option in the config which solved the issue.

like so:

```
browserName: 'chrome',
    'goog:chromeOptions': {
        // to run chrome headless the following flags are required
        // (see https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome)
        args: ["--headless", "--disable-gpu","--window-size=1280,672"]
        },
```